# Android Custom Layout have trouble in layout xml file with design mode

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I extend ConstraintLayout class for special purpose.
[image]

and I use this class in layout xml file.
[image]

not problem show layout.xml with text mode.

but try show layout.xml with Design mode,
android studio show me this message.

[image]

I already try 'Refresh', 'rebuild', 'clean build'.

but still show 'Missing classes'.

how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Have you added respective dependencies?

Comment: @nobalG no I have not. how can I add? is it right? -> compile 'kr.ac.dju.growthapp.NavigationBaseLayout'

Comment: Ok, the problem is that the path you are referencing to in xml does not exist. Either incorrect path to class or class doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are referencing to a class that doesn't exist or is not where you are referencing to.

You can either fix the path by

- Copying the class to the correct folder.
- Fixing the path by clicking on `Fix build path`
- Or, click on `Create Class` and copy everything you had in previous class into the new one.

I think the 3rd option will be the easiest for you.